# " No NVENC capable devices found" with ffmpeg for screen capture and RTP stream

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cuda, nvenc

I´m trying to stream my Desktop with RTP using ffmpeg.

libx264 seems to work fine. But I would like to test the performance of a hardware accelerated codec.

```
ffmpeg -re -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -an -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.1
```

The NVENC codec works fine in other situations like this

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 2000M -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1280x1080 -i desktop -c:v nvenc -preset:v fast -pix_fmt nv12 out.mp4
```

The Codec also apears in the list of available codecs.

However this command doesn´t work

```
ffmpeg -re -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec nvenc -preset llhq -an -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.1
```

My machine is a Windows 10 with GTX 760

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was wrong a few weeks ago.

Ffmpeg was expecting a GPU with CUDA 8, unfortunately GPUs with Kepler archtecture, like my 760,  have limited CUDA 8 features.

So NVENC could not properly work. The "solution" is to find a Ffmpeg release with CUDA 7 or 7.5 support.